# A continuous random variable and a Bernoulli random variable, that are independent, have a product that is a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Attempt:

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable and let B be a Bernoulli(p) random variable. Assume they are independent.

I need to show that the CDF 
$$
P(X\cdot B\leq z)
$$ 
can be expressed as 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^zf_{X\cdot B}(z)dz.
$$

I have
\begin{align}
P(X\cdot B\leq z) &= P\left(\bigcup_{(x,b)\in I(z)} X^{-1}(x)\cap B^{-1}(b)\right) \\
&\overbrace{=}^? \sum_{(x,b)\in I(z)} P(X=x,B=b) 
\end{align}
where $I(z):=\{(x,b)\in R\times \{0,1\} : x\cdot b <= z\}$ and the sum is defined in some sense. Are there any steps that I can fill in to make the equality marked with a question mark make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what you are after because some questions rise about have risen (What is $Y$ here? What is $f_{X\cdot Y}$? Further you speak of a *joint* CDF but it seems that you are after the CDF of a single random variable $XB$)

For $z\geq0$ we find:

$$P\left(XB\leq z\right)=P\left(XB\leq z\mid B=1\right)P\left(B=1\right)+P\left(XB\leq z\mid B=0\right)P\left(B=0\right)=$$$$P\left(X\leq z\mid B=1\right)p+P\left(0\leq z\mid B=0\right)\left(1-p\right)=$$$$P\left(X\leq z\right)p+1\left(1-p\right)=pF_{X}\left(z\right)+1-p$$

For $z<0$ we find:

$$P\left(XB\leq z\right)=P\left(XB\leq z\mid B=1\right)P\left(B=1\right)+P\left(XB\leq z\mid B=0\right)P\left(B=0\right)=$$$$P\left(X\leq z\mid B=1\right)p+P\left(0\leq z\mid B=0\right)\left(1-p\right)=$$$$P\left(X\leq z\right)p+0\left(1-p\right)=pF_{X}\left(z\right)$$

In both lines the third equality rests on independence.

So:

$$F_{XB}\left(z\right)=pF_{X}\left(z\right)+\left(1-p\right)\mathsf{1}_{\left[0,\infty\right)}\left(z\right)$$

Comment: Thank you. I apologise for the inconsistencies in my question. In your solution, the PDF of XB becomes $pf_X(z) + (1-p)\delta(z)$, where $\delta$ is the dirac delta function?

Comment: @Angelos I think so but must admit that I am not really familiar with the dirac-delta function. In my optics the random variable simply does not necessarily has a PDF because its CDF might not be continuous which I see as a necessity for having a PDF.

Comment: Does this mean that you would argue that $XB$ is not a continuous random variable, since $F_{XB}$ is discontinues due to the jump introduced by the indicator function?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. We have $P(XB=0)>0$ if $p<1$. Then $XB$ is not a continuous rv.